# Minimum value of $\frac{x^4+5x^2+7}{x^2+3}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, optimization, maxima-minima, a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Minimum value of $$f(x)=\frac{x^4+5x^2+7}{x^2+3}$$

we have $f(x)$ as 
$$f(x)=(x^2+3)+\frac{1}{x^2+3}-1$$

Now by $AM \gt GM$ we have

$$(x^2+3)+\frac{1}{x^2+3} \gt 2$$

But equality cannot occur since $$x^2+3 \ne \frac{1}{x^2+3}$$

But my question is without using calculus is there any way to find minimum using AM, GM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As an alternative, using your idea for decomposition, by [**Rearrangement inequality**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rearrangement_inequality) with

- $(a_1,a_2)=(\frac13,\frac{1}{(x^2+3)})$
- $(b_1,b_2)=\left(3(x^2+3),1\right)$

we have that

$$a_1b_1+a_2b_2=\frac13\cdot 3(x^2+3)+\frac{1}{(x^2+3)}\cdot 1= x^2+3+\frac{1}{(x^2+3)}\ge a_1b_2+a_2b_1=$$

$$=\frac13\cdot 1 +\frac{1}{(x^2+3)}\cdot 3(x^2+3)=\frac13+3=\frac{10}3$$

with equality for

$$a_1=a_2 \iff \frac13=\frac{1}{(x^2+3)}\iff x=0$$

therefore

$$f(x)=(x^2+3)+\frac{1}{x^2+3}-1\ge \frac{10}3-1=\frac 73$$

with the minimum attained at $x=0$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $a\geq 1$ be fixed.  Then, $g:[a,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $$g(t):=t+\frac{1}{t}\text{ for all }t\in[a,\infty)$$ is minimized at $t=a$.  To show this, write
$$g(t)-g(a)=(t-a)\left(1-\frac{1}{at}\right)\,.$$

---

With the Weighted AM-GM inequality, we note that
$$g(t)=a^2\,\left(\frac{t}{a^2}\right)+\frac{1}{t}\geq \left(a^2+1\right)\left(\left(\frac{t}{a^2}\right)^{a^2}\,\frac{1}{t}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^2+1}}=\left(a^2+1\right)\,\left(\frac{t^{a^2-1}}{a^{2a^2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^2+1}}\,\,.$$
Since $t\geq a\geq1$, we get
$$g(t)\geq \left(a^2+1\right)\,\left(\frac{a^{a^2-1}}{a^{2a^2}}\right)^{\frac{1}{a^2+1}}=\left(a^2+1\right)\,\frac{1}{a}=g(a)\,.$$

Answer (score 2):

For $x=0$ we get a value $\frac{7}{3}.$

We'll prove that it's a minimal value.

Indeed, we need to prove that
$$\frac{x^4+5x^2+7}{x^2+3}\geq\frac{7}{3}$$ or
$$x^2(3x^2+8)\geq0,$$ which is obvious.

Comment: that's nice but we need to guess at first that the minimum is at $x=0$

Comment: Yes, of course! It's not so hard.  After this we need to prove that for $x=0$ we'll get a minimal value, that I made.

Comment: Yes once we guess that the minimum is attained at $x=0$ the method is very good, but we need to guess that and in general it could be not so obvious to obtain. I've tried by rearrangement inequality. You can find of course some method to derive the result without any initial guessing. What about C-S? I would like to see some other method from your side.

Comment: @gimusi I think here it's a best way.

Comment: I absolutely dislike the initial guessing :)

Comment: But it's one of  ways for  proving inequalities and it's very useful. It's just an experience. In our case it's obvious that $f(x)=\frac{x^2+5x+7}{x+3}$ increases on $[0,+\infty).$

Comment: Why someone down voted?

Comment: I can't uderstand the downvote, it is a good answer of course and I gave +1 for that. I've only ciriticized a little bit in order to have a different answer without guessing! But your way to solve is very clear as usual. Bye

Answer (score 2):

Hint: We have

$$\frac{x^4+5x^2+7}{x^2+3}\geq 7/3$$ this is equivalent to

$$3x^4+15x^2+21\geq 7x^2+21$$

$$x^2(3x^2+8)\geq 0$$ the equal sign holds it $$x=0$$

Comment: that's nice but we need to guess at first that the minimum is at $x=0$

Comment: You have right, we can compute the first derivative additionally

Comment: Yes ok but the OP is asking for a method without derivatives. Your way is good but the initial guessing is a weakness point.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=f(x)$, then

\begin{align}
  0 &= x^4+(5-y)x^2+(7-3y) \\
  x^2 &= \frac{y-5 \pm \sqrt{(5-y)^2+4(\color{red}{3y-7})}}{2} \\
  &= \frac{y-5 \pm \sqrt{y^2+2y-3}}{2} \\
  &= \frac{y-5 \pm \sqrt{(y+3)(y-1)}}{2}
\end{align}

Now,

$$\Delta=(y+3)(y-1) \ge 0$$

Together with $f(x)>0$,

$$y \ge 1$$

in which $\Delta$ is increasing with $y$.

- When $y \ge 5$,

\begin{align}
  3y-7 & \ge 3(5)-7 \\
  & = 8 \\
  & > 0 \\
  \Delta & > \sqrt{(5-y)^2} \\
  & = y-5 \\
\end{align}

- When $1 \le y \le 5$,

\begin{align}
  y-5+\sqrt{(y+3)(y-1)} & \ge 0 \tag{$x^2 \ge 0$} \\
  (y+3)(y-1) & \ge (5-y)^2 \\
  4(\color{red}{3y-7}) & \ge 0 \\
  y & \ge \frac{7}{3} \\ 
\end{align}

The non-negativity of $x^2$ imposes $$x^2=\frac{y-5+\sqrt{(y+3)(y-1)}}{2}$$

which is increasing with $y$.

> The required minimum is $\frac{7}{3}$ which is achieved when
>
> $$x^2=\frac{\frac{7}{3}-5+5-\frac{7}{3}}{2}=0$$

[image]